# Angular ui.router, any result and any error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a little problem with my views in angular. I try to use ui.router to config my routes but it doesn't work. I try to use the console but it's clear. I don't know what i can do fix this problem.

```js
(function(){

  'use strict';

  const app = angular.module('myApp', ['common.services', 'common.servicesMock', 'ui.router']);
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("");

        $stateProvider
            .state('newList', {
                template: 'views/newsListView.html',
                url: '/news',
                controller: 'newsCtrl as vm',
            });

        //Delete the # in the routes
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({ 
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
        });
    });

}())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Wiki</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container">
    <div ui-view>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Libraries & Framweorks -->
  <script src="scripts/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/js/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

  <script src="scripts/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- App Scripts -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

  <!-- Controllers -->
  <script src="scripts/controllers/newsCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/categoriesCtrl.js"></script>

  <!-- Services -->
  <script src="scripts/common/services/common.services.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/common/services/categories/categoriesService.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/common/services/common.servicesMock.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/common/services/news/newsResource.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the view i want to show in the browser.

```js
<div class="row center" ng-controller="categoriesCtrl as vm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.toggleCategories()">{{vm.showCategories ? "Hide" : "Show"}} Categories</button>
        <br>
        <div ng-show="vm.showCategories" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active" ng-repeat="cate in vm.categories">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="{{cate}}" autocomplete="off">{{cate}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="title">Outstanding</legend>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="newsItem in vm.news | filter:{important: true} | orderBy: '-date'">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img ng-src='{{newsItem.banner}}' class="banner">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span class="date">{{newsItem.date | date}}</span>
                        <h3>{{newsItem.newsTitle}}</h3>
                        <p>
                            {{newsItem.newsDesciption.substring(0,200) + "..."}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="title">Last News</legend>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 thumbnail-xs" ng-repeat="newsItem in vm.news | filter:{important: false} | orderBy: '-date'">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img ng-src='{{newsItem.banner}}' class="banner">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <span class="date">{{newsItem.date | date}}</span>
                        <h3>{{newsItem.newsTitle}}</h3>
                        <p>
                            {{newsItem.newsDesciption.substring(0,200) + "..."}}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you declared the states, you need to actually "enter" the state when you first launch it. Assuming the `newList` state is the state that you want to go to, you can do it in two ways:

1. using `$urlRouterProvider` to route to `/news` at root:

   ```
   app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix("");

     $urlRouterProvider.when('/','/news');
     $stateProvider
       .state('newList', {
         template: 'views/newsListView.html',
         url: '/news',
         controller: 'newsCtrl as vm',
       });

     //Delete the # in the routes
     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
     });
   });
   ```
2. via `.run` method in angular

   ```
   app.run(['$state',function($state){
     $state.go('newList');
   }])
   ```